How to pass the inputs(bucket_name,key_name,file_name) of my previous state to glue job
I'm using s3 event for lambda trigger it consumes the bucket_name, key_name from it  and starts the step function, the step function consists of glue job for ETL function when the file is good format via a lambda function if not pushes to the archive folder, at the end of each workflow it sends sns message .
{
  "Comment": "A description of my state machine",
  "StartAt": "validate input csv",
  "States": {
    "validate input csv": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
      "OutputPath": "$",
      "Parameters": {
        "Payload.$": "$",
        "FunctionName": "****"
      },
      "ResultPath": "$.validation_result",
      "Next": "Choice"
    },
    "Choice": {
      "Type": "Choice",
      "Choices": [
        {
          "Variable": "$.validation_result.Payload.Validation",
          "StringEquals": "SUCCESS",
          "Next": "Glue StartJobRun"
        },
        {
          "Variable": "$.validation_result.Payload.Validation",
          "StringEquals": "FAILED",
          "Next": "move-file"
        }
      ]
    },
    "move-file": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
      "OutputPath": "$.Payload",
      "Parameters": {
        "Payload.$": "$",
        "FunctionName": "****"
      },
      "Next": "Error-alert"
    },
    "Glue StartJobRun": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::glue:startJobRun",
      "Parameters": {
        "JobName": "gluest",
        "bucket_name.$": "$.bucket_name",
        "folder_name.$": "$.key_name",
        "file_name.$": "$.file_name"
      },
      "Next": "archived-file"
    },
    "archived-file": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::sns:publish",
      "Parameters": {
        "TopicArn": "****",
        "Message": {
          "MESSAGE": "FILE IS ARCHIVED"
        }
      },
      "End": true
    },
    "Error-alert": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::sns:publish",
      "Parameters": {
        "TopicArn": "*****",
        "Message": {
          "message": "File not good mate !!"
        }
      },
      "End": true
    }
  }
}

Please find the glue job below , I also finding difficulty in writing the output logs out of my glue even though I gave the IAM roles perfectly ...For now I need my code to be good
import redshift_connector 
import pandas as pd
import boto3
import sys

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print(event)
    # Initialize Redshift Connector
    host = 'redshift-arn'
    port = 5439
    database = 'dev'
    user = 'admin'
    password = '*******'
    
    # Initialize Redshift Connector
    conn = redshift_connector.connect(
        host=host,
        port=port,
        database=database,
        user=user,
        password=password
    )
    
    # Access the values of the arguments
    bucket_name = event['bucket_name']
    key_name = event['key_name']
    file_name = event['file_name']
    result={}
    result['bucket_name']=bucket_name
    result['file_name']=file_name
    
    source_folder,source_file_name=os.path.split(key_name)
    print(source_folder)

    #Trying to push all the arguments into the result
    result['folder']=source_folder
    
    # Load CSV file into a Pandas DataFrame
    csv_file_path = f's3://{bucket_name}/{source_folder}/{file_name}'
    print(csv_file_path)
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_file_path)

    
    # Define the Redshift table name
    table_name = 'club_games'  # Change this to your actual Redshift table name
    
    # Define column names
    columns = ['game_id', 'club_id', 'own_goals', 'own_position', 'own_manager_name', 'opponent_id', 'opponent_goals', 'opponent_position', 'opponent_manager_name', 'hosting', 'is_win']
    
    # Write DataFrame to Redshift table
    
    # Create the Redshift table (if not exists)
    conn.execute(f"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {table_name} (game_id integer, club_id INT, own_goals INT, own_position INT, own_manager_name VARCHAR(50), opponent_id INT, opponent_goals INT, opponent_position INT, opponent_manager_name VARCHAR(50), hosting VARCHAR(20), is_win INT)")

    
        # Insert data into the Redshift table
    for _, row in df[columns].iterrows():
        values = ', '.join([f"'{value}'" if isinstance(value, str) else str(value) for value in row])
        insert_sql = f"INSERT INTO {table_name} VALUES ({values})"
        cursor.execute(insert_sql)
        conn.commit()
    
    # Archive the processed CSV file
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')

    archive_key='archive' + '/' + file_name 
    object_key= folder_name + '/' + file_name
    # Copy the file to the archive folder
    s3.copy_object(Bucket=bucket_name, CopySource={'Bucket': bucket_name, 'Key': object_key}, Key=archive_key)
    
    # Delete the original file from the input folder
    s3.delete_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=object_key)
    
    conn.commit()
    # Close the Redshift connection
    conn.close()
    return result

